# Why is my constructor for maps in a struct not working?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, constructor

This is the struct that I have and I'm trying to write the default constructor for that.

```
struct Cnode
{
typedef std::map<char, int> nextmap;
typedef std::map<char, int> prevmap;

Cnode() : nextmap(), prevmap() {} //error
Cnode(const nextmap2, const prevmap2) : nextmap(nextmap2), prevmap(prevmap2) {}

};
```

Please help me understand what this error means:

```
Type 'nextmap'(aka 'map<char,int>') is not a direct or virtualbase of 'Cnode'
Type 'prevmap'(aka 'map<char,int>') is not a direct or virtualbase of 'Cnode'
```

Comment: what is your intention? do you want `nextmap` to be a nested type or a field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `nextmap` and `prevmap` aren't variables, but types. As clearly indicated by the `typedef` (it defines a type).

Did you mean:

```
struct Cnode
{
std::map<char, int> nextmap;
std::map<char, int> prevmap;

Cnode() : 
  nextmap(), prevmap() {}
Cnode(const std::map<char, int>& nextmap2, const std::map<char, int>& prevmap2) : 
  nextmap(nextmap2), prevmap(prevmap2) {}

};
```

or perhaps this might clear your confusion:

```
struct Cnode
{
typedef std::map<char, int> MapOfCharToInt;  //defines a new type

MapOfCharToInt nextmap;                      //defines variables
MapOfCharToInt prevmap;                      //of that type

Cnode() : 
   nextmap(), prevmap() {} 
Cnode(const MapOfCharToInt& nextmap2, const MapOfCharToInt& prevmap2) : 
   nextmap(nextmap2), prevmap2(prevmap2) {}

};
```

Comment: OH! No, I don't want 2 variables under a single map. I need to be populating Cnode with 2 maps. Each of these maps should contain a list of char as key type and a list of ints as value type.

Comment: Okay, then how would I go about writing the constructors for 2 maps in a struct?

Comment: @sumrania oops, didn't see the other errors in the code. See edited answer.